# Как достать данные через подвязку?

Tags: php, yii

```
<?php 
    $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
    'id'=>'ref-mahala-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'district_id',
        'name_ru',
        'name_uz',
        'name_en',
        'address_ru',
         array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
         ),
    ),)); 
?>
```

В `дистрик_ид` приходят ид , по этому ид я должен достать запись из подвязки. Модель.

```
public function search()
{
    // @todo Please modify the following code 
    // to remove attributes that should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('district_id',$this->region['name_ru']);
    $criteria->compare('name_ru',$this->name_ru,true);
    $criteria->compare('name_en',$this->name_en,true);
    $criteria->compare('address_ru',$this->address_ru,true);
    $criteria->compare('address_en',$this->address_en,true);
    $criteria->compare('sort',$this->sort);
    $criteria->compare('active',$this->active);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
       'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'region' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'RefRegion', 'district_id'),
    );
}
```

Comment: Что такое подвязка?

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
    'id'=>'ref-mahala-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        array(
            'header'=> 'District',
            'value'=>'$data->region',
        ),
        'name_ru',
        'name_uz',
        'name_en',
        'address_ru',
        array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
```

Нужно обратиться к сводной записи через переменную `$data` (экземпляр класса модели).